# How to get ocean displacement waves?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, modifiers, shaders, dynamic-paint, ocean-simulation

I'm working on a scene where a ship moves in the ocean. But I'm not getting bow displacement waves.

[image]

Minor rendering errors are present.

Here are the settings for dynamic paint waves (brush):

[image]

I've done wave factor to negative values because I wanted to show foam stick to the body of the ship (brush). Please, anybody, suggest corrections or tell if it looks okay.
Also, the brush object is transparent here because I wanted to render the ship separately.

Comment: have you checked this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o2DjguaGeTY ?

Comment: @Peter Bro but I'm using an ocean modifier not a subdivided plane.